# flex cannot recognize character ranges

Tags: c, regex, flex-lexer

Here is the input file:

```
/* input.l */
%%
"[0-9]+" {printf("NUMBER: %s\n", yytext);}
"+" {printf("PLUS\n");}
"-" {printf("MINUS \n");}
"*" {printf("TIMES \n");}
"/" {printf("DIVIDE\n");}
"|" {printf("abs\n");}
"\n" {printf("NEWLINE\n");}
"[ \t]" {printf("WHITESPACE\n");} 
. {printf("UNKNOWN: %s\n", yytext);} 
%%
```

Compile and run:

```
flex -X input.l && cc lex.yy.c -lfl && ./a.out
a
UNKNOWN: a
NEWLINE
1
UNKNOWN: 1
NEWLINE
1 + 3
UNKNOWN: 1
UNKNOWN:
PLUS
UNKNOWN:
UNKNOWN: 3
NEWLINE
```

Note that flex missed both `[0-9]` and `[ \t]`.

Why did this happen?

OS: Ubuntu 18.10
flex version: 2.6.4

Comment: I don't know flex, but I think you should not quote the `[0-9]`.

Comment: I know a little Flex/Lex and I don’t think you should quote character ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a look at my flex code written years ago and I managed to make the following code work fine (tested on `Debian 9.5`). Just FYI.

(I forgot why the `yywrap()` is needed. :) )

```
[STEP 101] # cat foo.l
%%
[0-9]+ { printf("NUMBER: %s\n", yytext); }
"+"    { printf("PLUS\n"); }
"-"    { printf("MINUS \n"); }
"*"    { printf("TIMES \n"); }
"/"    { printf("DIVIDE\n"); }
"|"    { printf("abs\n"); }
"\n"   { printf("NEWLINE\n"); }
[ \t]+ { printf("WHITESPACE\n"); }
.      { printf("UNKNOWN: %s\n", yytext); }
%%

int yywrap(void)
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
[STEP 102] # flex foo.l
[STEP 103] # cc lex.yy.c
[STEP 104] # ./a.out
1 + 3
NUMBER: 1
WHITESPACE
PLUS
WHITESPACE
NUMBER: 3
NEWLINE
a
UNKNOWN: a
NEWLINE
[STEP 105] #
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you put quotes around the pattern. In (f)lex, characters inside double quotes have no special significance; they represent themselves (with the exception of `\`).

See the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns) for details on the syntax of patterns.